# Javascript regex expression text between """

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I get the text between `"""` and `"""` in javascript's regex?

Example:

`"""hello world"""` should give `hello world`

`""" hi """ """world"""` should give `[hi, world]`

Comment: Try `"{3}((?:(?!"{3}).)*)"{3}` - clean it using `trim`. You can also use `"{3}\s*((?:(?!"{3}).)*?)\s*"{3}` without `trim`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
(?<=""") ?\w+ ?( \w+)*(?=""")
```

explained

```
(?<=""")   --->   make sure three quotes appear prior to a word
 ?         --->   optional space
\w+        --->   match any word characters
( \w+)*    --->   match 0 or more spaced out words
(?+""")    --->   ensure that there's following close quotes
```

see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/6GuQ0F/1)

Comment: You should do more tests before posting: https://regex101.com/r/6wz0yF/2

Comment: @Toto thank you for bringing this to my attention, I'll admit slightly embarrassing, but I have corrected my error

Comment: Well, it's better but why do you limit the characers to word characters? This will not match `"""I've bought a phone that costs $1000.00""""`. Also lookbehind is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Toto I was going based on the OP's example strings, if you wish to capture everything in between triple quotes you can use this regex: ```(?<=""").+?(?=""")```  for a generic solution. If you have any further questions feel free to inbox me or post your own question to avoid spamming the current thread :) see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/xz6oSq/2

Comment: I don't have any question, I just tell you lookbehind doesn't work in all browsers, so your answer can't be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if OP is still searching for an answer, but you should try:

```
/"""([^"""]+)"""/g
```

This will match `""" hi """ """world""" """hello world"""` and even `"""I've bought a phone that costs $1000.00"""`